# Is threshold number of SCI papers a common recruitment criteria in the US?

Tags: publications, united-states, assistant-professor, india, recruiting

There are six types of higher educational institutions in the US according to [this source](https://carnegieclassifications.acenet.edu/classification_descriptions/basic.php)

1. Doctoral Universities (R1, R2, D/PU)
2. Master's Colleges and Universities (M1, M2, M3)
3. Baccalaureate Colleges (Arts & Sciences Focus, Diverse Fields)
4. Baccalaureate/Associate's Colleges
5. Associate's Colleges
6. Special Focus Institutions (2 years, 4 years)
7. Tribal Colleges

I am interested in knowing the general consensus, if any, of the recruitment criteria, based on the number of SCI papers published, of assistant professors among the top two types of institutes: Doctoral and masters.

I used to believe that recruitment, in general, doesn't depend on the number of SCI journals published and depends on experience(in years), projects handled, quality of papers published (if any), and quality of the PhD thesis, etc., I use to think that the quality of paper(s) matters more to the recruitment process compared to the number of papers. But I recently read reasons for rejection, citing that applicants have *less than 4 SCI journals*. You can check the [advertisement](https://www.iiitdmj.ac.in/jobs/download/Faculty/Assistant%20Professor%20advt%2003-2020.pdf) and [results](https://www.iiitdmj.ac.in/downloads/CSElevel11.pdf#page=2). There can be many examples like this. So, I am wondering whether the same with the top two types of institutes in the US.

Are there any such restrictions in the top two types of universities in the US? Do the top two types of universities *generally* reject the applicants citing the lack of such a minimum/ threshold number of SCI papers?

---

Those unaware of SCI/SCIE standards can read from [here](https://clarivate.com/webofsciencegroup/solutions/webofscience-scie/).

Comment: Note that there is overlap between the categories. And some are hard to classify. The Ivys are all private research universities, for example.

Comment: @Buffy - well, except for the NY state funded parts of Cornell...

Comment: Are there any issues with the question or people are simply down-voting?

Comment: @JonCuster, yes the exception that proves the rule. Some of my neighbors are Cornell ag school graduates even. Sorry to forget them.

Comment: IMO, downvotes on questions are sort of chaotic. Best to ignore them. Some are given (I think) for "You should have known this already." But that's just an opinion.

Comment: @Buffy Ha. The question was raised after reading some rejection statements. Possible. Will update.

Comment: Why would you believe that 'recruitment doesn't depend on the number of papers'? That could be a reason for some of the downvotes indeed.

Comment: @user2705196 I just updated and wrote the sentence you mentioned after down-votes. I use to believe as these reasons for rejection didn't use to exist before in India to the best of my knowledge. Top-tier universities may be exceptions.

Comment: Your "source" is terrible.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist oh! I am not aware of categorization in the US. So, I selected the one. I will try to update. Or please suggest me a link

Comment: @hanugm https://carnegieclassifications.acenet.edu/classification_descriptions/basic.php is a reliable source.  However, it's pointless to categorize universities in the US because there is no central authority that controls the universities.

Comment: Are we supposed to know what "SCI" means?  It seems strange to ask this question with no mention of any field of study.

Answer (score 6):

I doubt that in the US you will find any such "algorithmic" limitations. Every university is different. Every department is different. Every candidate is different. Every paper is different. Mere counts of publications capture very little.

While I can't rule it out universally, it is an *uncommon* practice here. (See below for the case of zero publications.)

A small number of good math papers with an indication of future productive activity may be enough, for example. And you can't compare math with experimental physics on numbers of papers.

Every candidate gets a thorough peer review of their record, not an administrative check list. Zero papers is probably a non-starter in many fields, of course, but not necessarily in all. Work in progress with high potential can count for something in a few cases. So can informal "sponsorship" by a senior professor who sees potential in a candidate.

And, of course, any new assistant professor will be reevaluated, perhaps a few times, before tenure is granted.

Comment: I doubt any US university would give so explicit of a reason for rejection in the first place, even if the first pass at applications had some algorithmic component (often HR screening against posted job requirements). Only leads to arguments that get nowhere.

Comment: @JonCuster ... Agreed. The linked example in the OP is an institute in India, established by the government of India.  As such it may have government-mandated transparency requirements that make such an algorithmic rejection system more likely.

Answer (score 6):

Universities in the US and most other western countries do not care at all if your publications have been indexed by SCI or any other indexes.  In many cases, they will not have heard of those indexes.

No thresholds are used in faculty hiring at universities in the US.  The number of publications is considered in the context of the reputations of the particular journals and the number of citations.

Get accurate information by viewing the public CVs of people who have the jobs you want.